# How to Automatically run the Deploy (No manual action) with Gitlab CI and Terraform?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

My gitlab ci pipeline always blocks the terraform deploy, requiring manual action to start it. Is it possible to make it automatic instead?

From [terraform gitlab yaml example](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform.gitlab-ci.yml)

```
stages:
  - validate
  - test
  - build
  - deploy
  - cleanup

sast:
  stage: test

include:
  - template: Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml  # https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Terraform/Base.gitlab-ci.yml

fmt:
  extends: .terraform:fmt
  needs: []

validate:
  extends: .terraform:validate
  needs: []

build:
  extends: .terraform:build

deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: start
  when: on_success

destroy:
  extends: .terraform:destroy
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: stop
  when: manual
```

Based on the documentation, `when: on_success` should automatically run the deploy command when the build stage succeeds. However, it still requires manual actions. Removing the when command is the same, it always requires a manual action to start the deploy.

Given I'm using gitlab's terraform template, is this hard coded to require manual actions to enable a deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a little while since I've worked on GitLab, but the template you reference has it as a [`rule`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#specify-when-jobs-run-with-rules):

```
.terraform:deploy: &terraform_deploy
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd "${TF_ROOT}"
    - gitlab-terraform apply
  resource_group: ${TF_STATE_NAME}
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: manual
```

Which is different from just the [`when`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when) keyword that you're using.

What if you tried overriding with with your own rule?

```
deploy:
  extends: .terraform:deploy
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: $TF_STATE_NAME
    action: start
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
      when: on_success
```

**Or better yet**, just create/manage your own template from a repo of your own.  Then you can modify the rules in there and delete the `when: manual` piece.